# Code always running on sheet to format col A - col AE based on value in p

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

I am trying to get a macro always to run on a sheet. The macro adds either a single or double line to the top edge of row range based on a cell value. My issue is that whenever I clear the sheet or try to run another macro to add data to the sheet every single line gets formatted. I know I need to have the "HR-Cal" sheet call this macro.

```
Sub reformat()
' harness double line
Dim rng As Range
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR-Cal")

With ws
    '~~> Find last row in Col Q
    lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Set your Find Range
    Set rng = .Range("Q5:Q" & lRow)

    '~~> Find (When searching for "*" after add "~" before it.
    Set aCell = rng.Find(What:="~" & .Range("AH2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
        With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AF" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlDouble
            .ThemeColor = 4
            .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
            .Weight = xlThick
        End With

        Do
            Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
                With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AE" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlDouble
                    .ThemeColor = 4
                    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            Else
               Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End With

' pos neg purpline top line
  With ws
    '~~> Find last row in Col Q
    lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Set your Find Range
    Set rng = .Range("Q5:Q" & lRow)

    '~~> Find (When searching for "*" after add "~" before it.
    Set aCell = rng.Find(What:="~" & .Range("AR2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
        With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AE" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -6279056
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
                End With

        Do
            Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
                With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AE" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -6279056
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
                End With
            Else
               Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End With
'
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know what your problem is. After clearing cells (including AH2 and AR2), this routine is automatically run; possibly through a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. Because there is nothing in the cell(s), too many cells are being found as matches to the empty cells.

```
Sub reformat()
    ' harness double line
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR-Cal")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Col Q
        lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Set your Find Range
        Set rng = .Range("Q5:Q" & lRow)

        ' pos neg purpline top double thick line IF AH2 has something in it.
        If CBool(Len(.Range("AH2").Value2)) Then
            '~~> Find (When searching for "*" after add "~" before it.
            Set aCell = rng.Find(What:="~" & .Range("AH2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            Set bCell = aCell
            Do While Not aCell Is Nothing
                '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
                With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AE" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlDouble
                    .ThemeColor = 4
                    .TintAndShade = 0.399945066682943
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With
                Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            Loop
        End If

        ' pos neg purpline top single thin line IF AR2 has something in it.
        If CBool(Len(.Range("AR2").Value2)) Then
            '~~> Find (When searching for "*" after add "~" before it.
            Set aCell = rng.Find(What:="~" & .Range("AR2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            Set bCell = aCell
            Do While Not aCell Is Nothing
                '~~> Create the necessary border that you are creating
                With .Range("A" & aCell.Row & ":AE" & aCell.Row).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .Color = -6279056
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            Loop
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

So I've added an If condition for each of the border drawing routines. This makes sure that either AH2 or AR2 is populated with something before using that cell(s) to locate rows in A:AE to put borders onto.

Some of your logic and procedures tended to repeat itself and I've tightened up those sections.

Comment: I will try this later today and let you know if this works